# include and use javascript-files in react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Long description, but short question. Is there a working example/guide that includes js-script in a React-app?**

Im creating a react app. I have bought a GUI theme and in the theme its two (minified) scripts are included. I want to use the theme to its fullest, i e, include those files in my React-project.
I have tried tips from [this article](https://medium.com/better-programming/4-ways-of-adding-external-js-files-in-reactjs-823f85de3668), but in best case, it doesnt seem to include the js-files in the build, since, when I click at one of the js-files in the Browsers' dev toolbar I only see the start html-page, and not the script.

Comment: You can include them using a `<script>` tag in your index.html, or you can `import` them in your app itself

Comment: ok, how do I import them? Lets say, I have them under src/Assets/js/app.min.js

Comment: This complete answer is probably specific to what you are using to build your app (create-react-app, NextJS, custom webpack config, etc). However, most likely you just want to add a `<script>` tag to your root html page, and put the minified scripts in whatever "public" area you have so you don't bundle them and just download them.

Comment: in your `index.html` add `<script src="/path/to/resource.js" type="text/javascript" />` (`resource.js` should be in `public` folder)

Comment: I have a index.html in my public-folder-folder... this is a resurrection of an old hobby-project so Im afraid I cant remember how I built it

Comment: ok, thanks. I guess that worked :)). This was the first I tested, but I must have messed something up...